# ANTLR: Combination of tokens

Tags: antlr

I have a question, I am searching for about an hour now. A given ANTLR-lexer rule consists of 2 (or more) sub-rules. The Lexer now produces separate AST-nodes.

Example:

```
[...]
variable: '$' CamelCaseIdentifier;
CamelCaseIdentifier: ('a'..'z') Identifier*;
Identifier: ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0'..'9')+;
[...]
```

With the given input of `[...]$a[...]` the result is `..., $, a, ...`

I am looking for a way to tell the lexer, that these rules should not be separated: `..., $a, ...`

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parser rules start with a lowercase letter and lexer rules with an upper case. When you output as an AST, each individual token in a parser rule will become a separate node, so you'll want to make the `variable` rule a lexer rule instead of a parser rule:

```
Variable            : '$' CamelCaseIdentifier;
CamelCaseIdentifier : ('a'..'z') Identifier*;
Identifier          : ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0'..'9')+;
```

But if you do it like this, the input `123456` will be tokenized as an `Identifier`, which is probably not what you want. Besides, the `Identifier` rule is better named `AlphaNum`. And if you make a fragment rule of it, you make sure the lexer will never produce any `AlphaNum` tokens on itself, but will only use `AlphaNum`'s for other lexer rules (like your `CamelCaseIdentifier` rule). If you also want a rule that matches an `Identifier`, do something like this:

```
Variable            : '$' (CamelCaseIdentifier | Identifier);
CamelCaseIdentifier : 'a'..'z' AlphaNum*;
Identifier          : 'A'..'Z' AlphaNum*;

// a fragment rule can't be used inside parser rules, only in lexer rules
fragment AlphaNum   : 'a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0'..'9';
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to uppercase all rule names?

Edited: With the example

```
grammar Dummy;

prog : VARIABLE*;

VARIABLE: '$' CAMELCASEIDENTIFIER;
CAMELCASEIDENTIFIER: ('a'..'z') IDENTIFIER*;
IDENTIFIER: ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0'..'9')+;


WS: (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN; };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner at compilers and Antlr, but from my limited understanding, a upper case (lexer) rule is only for regular expressions.  Lower case (parser) rules can also double as lexer rules (see [1]).  So it shouldn't matter if variable is upper or lower case, right?

Anyways, I may be wrong, but wouldn't it be simpler to just do this:

```
[...]
variable: '$' ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z') ALPHANUM*;
ALPHANUM: ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0'..'9');
[...]
```

?

If you plan on reusing ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z'), then you should do:

```
[...]
variable: '$' ALPHA ALPHANUM*;
fragment ALPHA: ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')
ALPHANUM: (ALPHA | '0'..'9');
[...]
```

Apologies if this is completely off base, I am still learning.

[1]  https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687210/Quick+Starter+on+Parser+Grammars+-+No+Past+Experience+Required